# Android WifiP2pManager how to know .connect(...) is failed?

Tags: android, connection, wifip2p

from documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#connect

I know we are notified when the connection is ***success*** by the BroadcastReceiver, as below:

```
    ...
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        if (mManager == null) {
            return;
        }

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

            // We are connected with the other device, request connection
            // info to find group owner IP

            mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel, connectionListener);
        }
        ...
```

How about the connection is ***failed***, anyone know how to catch it?

Comment: You just need to provide an ActionListener to the connect() method, the onSuccess() or onFailure() method will then be called. Have a look at the example in the link you provided.

Comment: Thank you @p2pkit, you can check carefully in the link, the onSuccess() and onFailure() is just for telling connect() method call made success or fail, it is an immediate result for the API call. It doesn't tell me whether the connection to target device made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this way can catch the connection attempt is failed:

```
...
else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        Log.i(TAG, "networkInfo: " + networkInfo.toString());

        ...
}
...
```

logcat show:
networkInfo: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI_P2P[], state: DISCONNECTED/***FAILED***, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, simId: 0

Comment: Thanks for mention using the Log, but what exactly does the error message mean?How to solve it ?? Mine message is:

NetworkInfo: [type: WIFI_P2P[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none)

Comment: Sorry I can't find it the documentation too